# How to store scraped data into a data frame within the scraping loop in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm new to web-scraping so I'm currently having trouble on how to store the data that I scraped into a data frame.

I think I need to create an empty list first and then store all the lists into the data frame, but I'm not sure how to do it within the loop and also store those with no data as `NA`.

Here is my code for scraping the data and storing them into different lists:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

title = c()
genre = c()
runtime = c()
imdb_rating = c()
votes_gross = c()

for (i in seq(2015, 2018, 1)) {
  link <- paste0("https://www.imdb.com/search/title?year=",i,"&title_type=feature&sort=boxoffice_gross_us,desc")
  top_movies <- read_html(link)

title_t <- top_movies %>% html_nodes(".lister-item-header") %>% html_text()
genre_t <- top_movies %>% html_nodes(".genre") %>% html_text()
runtime_t <- top_movies %>% html_nodes(".runtime") %>% html_text()
imdb_rating_t <- top_movies %>% html_nodes(".ratings-imdb-rating") %>% html_text()
votes_gross_t <- top_movies %>% html_nodes(".sort-num_votes-visible") %>% html_text()

title <- c(title, title_t)
genre <- c(genre, genre_t)
runtime <- c(runtime, runtime_t)
imdb_rating <- c(imdb_rating, imdb_rating_t)
votes_gross <- c(votes_gross, votes_gross_t)
}
```

This method generates inconsistent result as some movies don't have rating or votes data. So, I'm not sure how to make them as `NA` and store all data into a data frame.

Comment: This question and answer is very similar to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51336519/rvest-how-to-have-na-values-in-html-nodes-for-creating-datatables/51340297#51340297.  Please verify that you are not violating the terms of service on the website you are attempting to scrape.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't solve my problem